# XSLT converting a complex realtime XML to a meaningful flat XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a question about XSLT. I am a newbie. Reading through forums and trying to get the desired formatted output of my XML.

As you can see, based on `$<DataSources>` Tag attribute `TYPEID`, its child `NODES` vary.

What I am trying to achieve here is to

1. FLATTEN the hierarchy of XML
2. out put certain TAGS
3. Convert TAGS like `<expression>` which in turn contains other child nodes or tags instead of a TEXT() value to an expression of this format

   (AND)   ..((((EventDisplayNumber)(equal)(823)))... ..and so on

So far I am only able to convert all Attributes to ELEMENTS as a first step to Flatten the XML.

Next step is to break heirarchy and convert deep nested XML tags into symbolic expressions in mathematical notation.

Third will be to select desired NODES out of the previous output.

Please suggest or help as I am totally stumped as how should I proceed next.

INPUT::

```
<Rule ID="SpaceLeftPercent." Enabled="true" Target="DBFileGroup"    >
    <Category>PerformanceCollection</Category> 
    <DataSources>
        <DataSource ID="DS" TypeID="DBFileGroupSizeOptimizedPerfProvider">
            <IntervalSeconds>900</IntervalSeconds>
            <SyncTime /> 
            <ConnectionString> ConnectionString$</ConnectionString>
            <ServerName> NetworkName$</ServerName>
            <SqlInstanceName> InstanceName$</SqlInstanceName>
            <ObjectName> PerformanceCounterObject$ : Database : File Group</ObjectName>
            <CounterName>DB File Group Allocated Space Left (%)</CounterName>
            <InstanceName> GroupName$</InstanceName>
            <DatabaseName> DatabaseName$</DatabaseName>
            <DBFileGroupId>GroupID$</DBFileGroupId>
            <Value>$Data/Property[@Name='FreeSpaceAutoGrowPercent']$</Value>
            <Tolerance>10</Tolerance>
            <ToleranceType>Absolute</ToleranceType>
            <MaximumSampleSeparation>4</MaximumSampleSeparation>
            <TimeoutSeconds>300</TimeoutSeconds>
        </DataSource>
    </DataSources> 
</Rule>
```

---

```
<Rule ID=" id823" Enabled="true"  ConfirmDelivery="true" Remotable="true" >
    <Category>EventCollection</Category>
    <DataSources>
        <DataSource ID="DS" TypeID="Windows!Microsoft.Windows.EventProvider">
            <ComputerName>NetworkName$</ComputerName>
            <LogName>Application</LogName>
            <Expression>
                <And>
                    <Expression>
                        <SimpleExpression>
                            <ValueExpression>
                                <XPathQuery Type="UnsignedInteger">EventDisplayNumber</XPathQuery>
                            </ValueExpression>
                            <Operator>Equal</Operator>
                            <ValueExpression>
                                <Value Type="UnsignedInteger">823</Value>
                            </ValueExpression>
                        </SimpleExpression>
                    </Expression>
                    <Expression>
                        <SimpleExpression>
                            <ValueExpression>
                                <XPathQuery Type="String">PublisherName</XPathQuery>
                            </ValueExpression>
                            <Operator>Equal</Operator>
                            <ValueExpression>
                                <Value Type="String"> ServiceName$</Value>
                            </ValueExpression>
                        </SimpleExpression>
                    </Expression>
                </And>
            </Expression>
        </DataSource>
    </DataSources>
    <WriteActions>
        <WriteAction  >
            <Priority>2</Priority>
            <Severity>2</Severity>
            <AlertName />
            <AlertDescription />
            <AlertOwner />

            <AlertParameters>
                <AlertParameter1>$Data/EventDescription$</AlertParameter1>
            </AlertParameters>
            <Suppression>
                <SuppressionValue />
            </Suppression>

        </WriteAction>
    </WriteActions>
</Rule>
```

MY CURRENT XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*/Rule/DataSources/DataSource">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">  
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template name="resolveexpr" match="/*/Rule/DataSources/DataSource">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(name(.),'Expression')">
                <xsl:text>sometext</xsl:text>   
            </xsl:when>     
            <xsl:otherwise />
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

OUTPUT DESIRED:
SOmething like below.
But My end Goal is to bring this into an excel sheet.

```
<Rule>
  <ID>id823</ID>
  <Enabled>true</Enabled>
  <ConfirmDelivery>true</ConfirmDelivery>
  <Remotable>true</Remotable >
  <Category>EventCollection</Category>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource>
      <TypeID>Windows!Microsoft.Windows.EventProvider>
      <ComputerName>NetworkName$</ComputerName>
      <LogName>Application</LogName>
      <Expression>
        <And>((((EventDisplayNumber))(Equal)((823))))((((PublisherName))(Equal)(( ServiceName$))))</And>
      </Expression>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <WriteActions>
    <WriteAction  >
      <Priority>2</Priority>
      <Severity>2</Severity>
      <AlertParameters>
        <AlertParameter1>$Data/EventDescription$</AlertParameter1>
      </AlertParameters>
      <Suppression>
        <SuppressionValue />
      </Suppression>
    </WriteAction>
  </WriteActions>
</Rule>
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show the output you expect in this case? It may also help if you indented your XML sample too. Thanks!

Comment: Flat is usually _less_ meaningful. Hierarchy communicates context.

Comment: @Tim I added the desired output, also indented.

Comment: @keshlam need it flat for only reason to import it in excel for users to view the stuff.

Comment: Sanity check: Your two `<Rule>` samples above are two separate input documents, right? A well-formed XML document has a single top-level element...

Comment: No keshlam, it is a single document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've started off on the right track by using the Identity Template, although from the looks of your example you want to convert attributes in to elements. Therefore you need to remove the `@*` pattern from the identity template match, and create another template to match attributes.

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">  
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The other templates you need will probably relate to building up the expression. You haven't really explained the full logic for this, but it looks like a case of outputting the values surrounded by parentheses. Something like this

```
<xsl:template match="SimpleExpression">
    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
   <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ValueExpression|Operator">
    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

It also looks like you only want to output the top most **Expression** element, so you would need a template to skip over any descendant ones

```
<xsl:template match="Expression[ancestor::Expression]">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Elements like **And** would be scooped up by the identity transform.

Try this XSLT. This may not give you exactly what you need, but it should give you more of a start to point you on your way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">  
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Expression[ancestor::Expression]">
            <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SimpleExpression">
        <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
       <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="ValueExpression|Operator">
        <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```